# storing date with laravel and react js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, sorting, store

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $formattedDateHeader = Carbon::parse($request->input('date'))->toDateString();


        $reservation = Reservation::create([
            'fullname'          => $request->input('fullname'),
            'service_meet'      => $request->input('service_meet'),
            'date'              => $formattedDateHeader,
            'start_date_time'   => $request->input('start_date_time'),
            'end_date_time'     => $request->input('end_date_time'),
            'status'            => 'en cours', // Set default status
            'salle_id'          => $request->input('salle_id'),
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'reservation passed successfully',
            'reservation' => $reservation
        ]);
    }
```

i want to store a the date for the rservation so this component is for datepicker (Using Mui react);
and when i pick a date like 2024/02/02 its storing the date of today (the current date) . i tried to change format of date and i still have the same issue
#its correctly storing the reservation , this is an example

```
{status: 200, message: 'reservation passed successfully', reservation: {…}}
message: "reservation passed successfully"
reservation: created_at: "2023-12-06T17:01:27.000000Z"
date: "2023-12-06" (here is the issue)
end_date_time: "22:01"
fullname: "ademo tens"
id: 20
salle_id: 9
service_meet: "meeting1"
start_date_time: "18:05"
status: "en cours"
updated_at: "2023-12-06T17:01:27.000000Z"
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure the date is getting passed correctly. Use `Log::info($request->all());`, then check the logs in `storage/logs` to see what's being passed in.

Comment: const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);
    setSelectedDate(newDate, () => {
      console.log(selectedDate); // This will log the updated value
    });};
  return (
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker"
          name='date'
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is related to Laravel. But there're multiple reasons can cause it. Here most common issues:

1. Check the Format of the Incoming Date (in my example it's Y-m-d)

   $formattedDateHeader = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input('date'))->toDateString();
2. Check that you actually get date in the api

   \Log::info('Parsed date:', ['date' => $parsedDate->toDateString()]);
3. Check that 'date' field is fillable in the Reservation model.

   protected $fillable = [..., 'date'];